# sampling for small population sizes and multiple outcomes

Tags: sampling

What's the right formula to determine sampling size (without replacement) for a small population and multiple groups?

I have a population of N = few hundred events (per month) where I'd like to evaluate a YES/NO question that applies only only one group (for example 40% of all events.) Given a precision (+/-10%) and a confidence interval (90%,) what's the sample size required?

Ideally I'd prefer to simply select a sample and evaluate it, rather than having to first remove the events associated with the group that's not relevant and then still ensure my sample size is large enough.